# How to get list of charge ids for CONNECTED ACCOUNT payout object in stripe

Tags: stripe-payments

I store the id from each Charge and associate with a purchase.
I have connected accounts in my application. I want to show them the breakdown of purchases per payout. To do that I need a way to get the list of charge_ids per payout.

Comment: Absolutely, you could make use of the Balance History API, which you could pass in payout id and list all the transaction types including charges, refunds etc. You could filter out by the Transaction Type during the query as well. https://stripe.com/docs/api/balance/balance_history#balance_history-payout

Comment: it does not list the original charge ids, only the ids of transfers from the master account. the only way to get the original charge_id that i found was this:
get all balance transactions for a payout
get all charges for a connected account
map charges to balance transactions 
for each connected account charge find the source_transaction and look up the charge in the master account.
Obviously not very efficient.

Answer (score 0):

I received an official response from stripe, there is no way to do it in one query but there is a way.

> 1) a charge ch_xxxx and a related transaction (txn_xxxxxx) is created
>   on platform account
>
> After the platform receives the charge, platform account will create a
>   transfer to the connected account (tr_xxxxxx) and the transfer object
>   is on Platform Account as well
>
> 2) When connected account received the transfer, an payment object
>   will be created (py_xxxxxx) and a related transaction (txn_xxxxx)   On
>   the connected account, these payment transactions will be grouped
>   together and paid out in a "po_xxxxxx"
>
> So between platform account and connected account, from connected
>   account payout to charge, the overall flow looks like this:
>
> payout (po_xxxx) -> transactions (txn_xxxx) -> payment(py_xxxx) ->
>   transfer(tr_xxxx) -> charge (ch_xxxxx)

```
    public static void ListTransactionsForPayout(String payout) throws StripeException {

//1. Get a list of transactions for payout in Connected account 
 Map<String, Object> balancetransactionParams = new HashMap<String, Object>();
 balancetransactionParams.put("limit", 20);
 balancetransactionParams.put("payout", "po_1Dy8ZfKxxxxxx"); 

 List<String> expandList = new LinkedList<String>();
 expandList.add("data.source");
 balancetransactionParams.put("expand", expandList);


 RequestOptions requestOptions = RequestOptions.builder()
            .setStripeAccount("acct_connected_account")
            .build();

 BalanceTransactionCollection transactions = BalanceTransaction.list(balancetransactionParams, requestOptions);

 for (BalanceTransaction txn : transactions.autoPagingIterable()) {
 if (txn.getType().equals("payment")) {
 Charge charge = (Charge) txn.getSourceObject();

// 2. Get transfers from payment and get charge from transfer 
 Transfer transfer = Transfer.retrieve(charge.getSourceTransfer());
 System.out.printf("txn %s -> payment %s -> transfer %s -> charge %s\n", txn.getId(), txn.getSource(), transfer.getId(), transfer.getSourceTransaction());
            }
        }
    }
```